# Running cucumber on Nitrous.io

Tags: ruby, cucumber, nitrousio

I have a rails app and I am using a nitrous.io box to develop it. I am trying to run my cucumber features but I am getting an error because firefox is not install. I tried to install firefox but the security settings of the box does not allow me to do.

It there a way to run cucumber features on a nitrous box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will not be able to utilize a web browser within the web IDE, you will want to utilize [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). You can install the latest version with the Autoparts package manager:

```
parts install phantomjs
```

Once installed, you will need to configure your rails app to utilize it. There are many articles which will help you out with this. Here is a bit from [blog.pezholio.co.uk](http://blog.pezholio.co.uk/2013/04/automated-testing-with-cucumber-and-phantom-dot-js/) which covers using PhantomJS with Cucumber:

"
I’m assuming you’ve got Cucumber-rails set up in your Rails app already, so if you haven’t, take a look at this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber) to get you started.

Next, add poltergeist to your gemfile (probably in your :test group) like so:

```
gem 'poltergeist'
```

and run `bundle install`

The next thing to do is register Poltergeist as a new browser in Cucumber, and make it run as the default driver for all your JavaScript tests. Open up your features/support/env.rb file and add the following lines:

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {debug: false})
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

Then you should be good to go! Crucially, you need to make sure you add the @javascript tag to all your tests, so Capybara knows to use Poltergeist for your tests, but other than that, when you now run your tests, rather than a browser window being fired up, everything happens in the background like magic!
"